# Custom Scrollbar not working on body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a really simple code which is supposed to have a custom scrollbar on its body.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://malihu.github.io/custom-scrollbar/3.0.0/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
        $('body').mCustomScrollbar({
                theme:"dark-3"
        });
});
</script>
<style>
html,body{ height: 100%; }
body{ overflow: auto; }
p{
        font-family: Arial;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 1px auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse molestie dolor eget porta semper. Phasellus vehicula lorem ac augue pulvinar, quis porta metus sagittis. Nunc congue, est in interdum ultricies, sapien enim semper libero, nec tempus dolor neque sed ligula. Maecenas euismod ante ac varius cursus. Aliquam faucibus rutrum commodo. Duis ultricies pharetra ex. Proin faucibus volutpat vestibulum.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's so simple yet I can't get it to work. 
Can somebody help me out, please?

Comment: chrome console (F12) is showing a Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, jQuery always needs to be the first imported code.. moved it up to the top and it worked great.